# Searching ArrayList of Objects in Java

Tags: java, search, arraylist, iterator

I'm building a small application (for fun) to basically track employees and products in a java app. I have created the arraylists and the classes but I'm having trouble sorting through them and searching.. Here is what I have tried so far..

I'm trying to search the objects of the arraylist based off of employee name

```
System.out.println("Enter name of employee to search: \n");
String name = keyboard.nextLine();
Iterator itr = employeeList.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Employee test = (Employee) itr.next();

    if (test.getFirstName() == name.toString()) {
    System.out.println(test.getEmpInfo());

    }
}
```

My dilema is that if I replace the name.toString() with the name in quotes it works, but if I use the keyboard.nextLine() it won't work, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most common problem in java beginners. **Use `equals()` method instead of `==` to compare `Strings` with java.** So modify your code as follows.

```
if (test.getFirstName().equals(name.toString())) {
     //your code
}
```

**NOTE:** `==` is used to compare binary equality, which compares the memory location of objects. But `.equals()`  is possible to override and it compares the value of objects according to specified logic.

Comment: Thanks! 

I did this and it worked... is there a more efficient way? 
'
                            if (test.getFirstName().equals(name.toString())) {
                                System.out.println(test.getEmpInfo());
                                
                            }'

Comment: yes, that's the only method you can use. sometimes you may no need to `name.toString()` if name is a String value.

Comment: True, there is no scenario in this case where it could be a string, but I have been trying to ensure that I handle all possible errors and doing best practice but you raise a good point.. thanks for the help!

Comment: @TylerH You could use a `foreach`, which is usually faster than a `while` or `for` when using `ArrayList`s. You could also use a stream filter, which should be the most efficient way to do this: `employeeList.stream().filter(anEmployee -> anEmployee.getFirstName().equals(name)).forEach(anEmployee -> System.out.println(anEmployee.getEmpInfo()));` I wrote a little example on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/qhLS5Y1B